# Why is this causing a Memory Allocation Failure?

Tags: series-expansion, memory

This code causes an error.  Why?  It works fine if I cut the polynomial ff off at 12 terms instead of 15, but I can't understand why that would make a difference.  Is the Series[] function just managing memory internally in some inefficient way?

```
ff = -((1 + Log[2 \[Pi]])/2) - a^2/2 + a^4/4 - a^6/6 + (5 a^8)/24 - (13 a^10)/30 + (227 a^12)/180 - (2957 a^14)/630 + (21425 a^16)/  1008 - (642853 a^18)/5670 + (39471647 a^20)/56700 - (1508015087 a^22)/311850 + (28060338023 a^24)/748440 - (3903318402161 a^26)/12162150 + (511917869636359 a^28)/170270100 - (39068344168303909 a^30)/1277025750; 
bb = Series[-Log[((1 + Log[8*Pi])/2 + ff)/Log[2]], {a, 0, 30}] // FullSimplify;
```

Results:

```
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException]. >>
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
```

Comment: No problem with `Simplify`.  It's the `FullSimplify` that does it.

Comment: And you get a much simpler and probably more useful output with `N` which you can output to any precision you want since you are using exact numbers.

Comment: @BillWatts  Thanks but... I don't get why FullSimplify would do that.

Comment: `FullSimplify` has much more overhead and takes a lot longer than `Simplify`.  Also, you get a much simpler expression if you use `Simplify` after `Normal` for `Series`.

Comment: You did nothing wrong. The low level implementation of `FullSimplify` seems to have a bug. Please notify Wolfram Support about. The only people who can tell you why this happens are the developers.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Will do. Thanks!